# How to change the format within a TOC?

Tags: table-of-contents, appendix

I am writing a book using the `book` class. In the table of contents, I want

PART 1 Whatever
Chapter 1 whatever
...
and then to switch, in the appendices to

APPENDICES
Appendix A Whatever
...

I cannot seem to get `LaTeX` to recognize the `\renewcommand` to change from Part to blank and Chapter to Appendix. I can't seem to get rid of the `PART" before APPENDICES without getting rid of it on all the other sections, or to change` Chapter" to "Appendix"

I would also like to delete the page numbers on pages 1, 9 and 15. I have tried placing `\thispagestyle{empty}` in various places in the document, but to no avail.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftpartpagefont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftpartpresnum}{PART~}
\renewcommand{\cftpartaftersnum}{:}
\renewcommand{\cftpartnumwidth}{6em}

\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter~}
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{:}
\renewcommand{\cftchapnumwidth}{6em}



\frontmatter
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\renewcommand\partname{PART}
\part{Theory of Junk}
\input{Ch1}
\input{Ch2}
\input{Ch3}

\part{Theory of Garbage}
\input{Ch4}
\input{Ch5}


\renewcommand\partname{}
\renewcommand\thepart{\null}
\renewcommand{\cftpartpresnum}{}

\part{APPENDICES}
\appendix
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Appendix~}
\input{A1}
\input{A2}


\backmatter
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the changes into the TOC using `\addtocontents`:

```latex
\addtocontents{toc}{%
  \protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftpartpresnum}{}%
  \protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappresnum}{Appendix~}%
  \protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchapnumwidth}{7em}%
}%
```

Example without package `appendix`:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
%\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}% not used in the example
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftpartpagefont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftpartpresnum}{PART~}
\renewcommand{\cftpartaftersnum}{:}
\renewcommand{\cftpartnumwidth}{6em}

\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter~}
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{:}
\renewcommand{\cftchapnumwidth}{6em}

\renewcommand{\partname}{PART}

\newcommand{\originalappendix}{}
\let\originalappendix\appendix
\renewcommand{\appendix}{%
  \originalappendix
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftpartpresnum}{}%
    \protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappresnum}{Appendix~}%
    \protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchapnumwidth}{7em}%
  }%
  \cleardoublepage
  \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{APPENDICES}%
  \part*{APPENDICES}%
}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\part{Theory of Junk}
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\part{Theory of Garbage}
\blinddocument
\blinddocument

\appendix
\blinddocument
\blinddocument

%\backmatter
\end{document}
```

[image]